# DBpedia SPARQL query for song information for ID3 tag

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, id3

I am trying to properly tag all my music. I have already iterated my music through musicbrainz picard and MediaGo but Still Some of the songs are not tagged or partially tagged.
I came across the DBpedia and SPARQL. Now the query I want to ask to SPARQL is, 
" Show me all the music albums between 2010-2015, It's Album Artist, All titles in the album, Genere, Release Year and Cover art " 
At first I tried the following query but I am unable to understand how it is not showing all the albums. I searched "Hybrid Theory" which was not there.

```
PREFIX dbpedia0: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?album ?album_name WHERE {
?album a dbpedia0:Album .
?album dbpedia2:name ?album_name .
}
```

I also want to search album/film music info later, specifically in Cinema_of_India class.

Please guide me to the  right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With DBpedia, you first need to define the type of instance you are trying to extract. In this particular example, you are looking for albums thus:

```
?album a dbpedia-owl:Album .
```

Then you need to look for properties that belong to this album. As you have named them, you are looking for:

```
rdfs:label
dbpedia-owl:artist
dbpedia-owl:genre
dbpedia-owl:releaseDate
dbpprop:title
```

And lastly, you want to filter your album names only to contain English (or whatever language you are looking for) labels. Also, you have a constraint on your release date.

```
SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
    ?album a dbpedia-owl:Album .
    ?album rdfs:label ?albumName.
    ?album dbpedia-owl:artist ?Artist.
Optional{
    ?album dbpedia-owl:genre ?genre.
    ?album dbpedia-owl:releaseDate ?date.
    ?album dbpprop:title ?title.
}
Filter ( 
    lang(?albumName)='en' && 
    xsd:dateTime(?date) >= '2010-01-01T00:00:00Z'^^xsd:dateTime)
}
```

The reason I put some of the variables in the optional is that if there is an album that DBpedia doesn't contain these information, it will still show up.

You next query, also needs to follow that same logic. For example, if you are looking for a specific album you could use this query and get other restrictions on the album.

```
SELECT distinct * WHERE { 
    ?album a dbpedia-owl:Album.
Filter( ?album=dbpedia:Hybrid_Theory)
}
```

Comment: Great to start with !! Clean and understandable !! And thanks for proper explanation.I edited the filter block with `Filter ( 
    lang(?albumName)='en' && 
    xsd:dateTime(?date) >= '1990-01-01T00:00:00Z'^^xsd:dateTime)
}` to see the album **Hybrid Theory** (Released 1999/2000) , but I did not find this album in the query output. I went through the dbpedia.org/page/Hybrid_Theory to see that artist and label exist. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Even I can not see the Hybrid Theory album with the following query,                            `SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
    ?album a dbpedia-owl:Album .}`                                                                                                                                      Eventhough [dbpedia.org/page/Hybrid_Theory](http://dbpedia.org/page/Hybrid_Theory) has the property `dbpedia-owl:Album` under `rdf:type`

Comment: Your main query has addressed my question but I think there may be some problem with `dbpedia` as it doesn't find some (eg. **Hybrid_Theory**) albums even though the album exist in `dbpedia` database. Even the specific query for **Hybrid_Theory** resulted null. So I don't know whether the problem is with `dbpedia` or with the query script. If the problem is with `dbpedia` I will make this thread as answered and ask another question. So please run the script by yourself to find-out the problem and share the reason.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you add `?album=dbpedia:Hybrid_Theory` to the filter of the main query I wrote, it will find it. The only reason I can think of when not finding a record is that one of the main variables (e.g. ?album, ?albumName, or ?artist) doesn't exist and thus the query will disregard them.

Comment: I checked the dbpedia page associated with Hybrid_Theory [dbpedia.org/page/Hybrid_Theory](http://dbpedia.org/page/Hybrid_Theory). It is a `dbpedia-owl:Album`. Then why this album doesn't show up in the results then ? I request you to go to [http://dbpedia.org/snorql](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/) write/paste the query and see it yourself.

Comment: There is something wrong with the endpoint try it at http://dbpedia.org/sparql. It comes up

Comment: Tried It with [dbpedia.org/sparql](http://dbpedia.org/sparql). Finally I am able to find **Hybrid_Theory** in the query result. Though the 1st script in your answer does not find the album **Hybrid_Theory** with following filter `Filter ( lang(?albumName)='en' && xsd:dateTime(?date) >= '1990-01-01T00:00:00Z'^^xsd:dateTime) }`. Is there any max result limitation or something else from the server side ? I am not getting timeout error.

Comment: Yes, I think it limits the output. If you replace `*` with `?album` it shows up. So I suspect that the endpoint is limiting the result set.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. Now I can see improved result. As a workaround I need to filter month by month which is time consuming and less automated.